# svn can't connection to server with error's E170013 Unable to connect to a repository at URL; E210002 network connection closed unexpectedly

Tags: windows, svn, connection, repository, tortoisesvn

i'm having a problem with SVN.

Exist NEW four PC with NEW W10. I'm installing TortoiseSVN v1.9-1.14
To all PC can't connect to repository svn://xxx.XXX.xxx/XXXX with error's E170013 Unable to connect to a repository at URL; E210002 network connection closed unexpectedly.

To other pc in domen everything is fine, repo connecting, window authorization show up, and worked.

I'm launch debugview of MS. and starting connect - no request from program to server
CMD NetStat - no request to server or port 3690
WireShark - no request.

RUN CMD
svn co server -errors

This four pc it new compilation hardware in domen network maybe problem in new compilation?
Any ideas what I'm missing.

Comment: telnet server port 3690 - connect